# How to highlight the particular text in a tag and format the text (like Bold, Italic and so on) using Robot Framework

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I have a text in div tag as **"Robot Framework tutorials"**

I wanted to highlight only **"Robot"** and mark it as bold using **Robot framework**.

> Can anyone help me how to highlight the text ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try selecting this text to highlight it. For example:

[image]

1. Focus on the text you want to highlight
2. Divide it into substrings and find which substring you want to highlight
3. Select the substring to highlight it

Comment: *** Setting *** Library Selenium2Library Library String *** Test Cases *** Get subselection ${string}= Get Text xpath=/html/div ${substring}= Get Substring ${string} 25 35      I have used this code, and able to get substring  but how to select it using robot framework

Comment: @Uday, from what I can recall, there is no established keyword that enables you to do it by default, but you can add your own keyword to Robot framework.

Comment: Yea that is what the problem, I am unable to select the text, need someone who is expert in Javascript to help me out on this